# MediumBLOB will not support a 4KB File - Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, blob, innodb

So yeah, I am adding billing documents as data and as XML in a Mediumblob column to then query it and export as PDF
but the error says

Data too long for column 'XML' at row 1

max_allowed_packet is currently 16777216 both in my.ini and in the database.
Innodb log was raised from 8M to 16 even 32 Mand still fails

What would i be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: have you restarted the mysql instance after making changes?

Comment: I restarted the service, had to delete the log files, but the server started sucessfully.

Comment: I forgot to say that we are using 5.5 beacuse our boss doens't want to upgrade it beacuse of compatibility with windows 2000 (who am i to blame), but seems there' a bug that MAY be related to this, i am reinstalling the sql server to 5.7.21 to see if it has any relation or not.

Comment: Issue remains with MYSQL 5.7.2.1

Comment: yeah i see that

Comment: The bill file i am adding to the database if i has more than 117 lines fails, otherwise it works fine

Comment: exactly. I recommend its not a good idea store files inside database

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/NJ1v8r0.png Is this a bad idea then?

Comment: I have encountered multiple performance issues when stored in blob. Later I moved it to file system.

Comment: That would require a rewrite of the entire code, i deleted every single dll file of mysql.data.dll, and leaving only version 6.9.9.0, this stopped the "Data too long for column" but, of the 60 products in the invoice, it only reaches up to 58 and deletes the remaining 40-60 lines in the final xml, so pdf invoice can't be exported and printed.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `INSERT` statement.  Plus the byte length of the blob.  There may be something subtle that will show up in this info -- especially if the problem persists into 5.7.

Comment: Also, since XML is defined to be UTF-8, did you try `MEDIUMTEXT` instead of `MEDIUMBLOB`?